# Android: How to load an Activity inside of an ActionBarSherlock Tab?

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am starting with ActionBarSherlock.

I know how to load content (other activity for example) in a tab without this library but I haven't find how to do it with Sherlock.

In a normal case I usually create a new Intent and load it through "setContent":

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SQLFavouritesFragmentActivity.class);
spec.setContent(intent);
```

In Sherlock I have seen a method called "onTabSelected" but I don't know how to use it neither how to relate with tabs.

any suggestion, idea or tutorial?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities as being the contents of tabs has been deprecated. There is no support in ActionBarSherlock, or the native action bar, for hosting an activity in a tab.

If you convert the activity in question to be a fragment, you can load the fragment into your UI when the tab is selected.